# how to check if a data exist on a table using hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, authentication

im using hibernate with my jsp page and mySQL ,how can i do that  `select * from student wher userName = ***` with HQL

and how i chek if that username exist in 'Student' table ?

in my sql i use that

```
ResultSet resultat = statement.executeQuery();

if (resultat.next()) { ....}
```

i try this

```
Session hibernateSession = MyDB.HibernateUtil.currentSession(); 
hibernateSession.find("select xxx from Etudinat where p.Nom=xxxx");
```

its give me a list but

i have a login form send me a username and password

i want to chek if that username exist in the table Student to set the user on a session

what is the safty way to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not paste code into the comment. Try the following HQL:

```
from Etudinat where Nom = 'xxxx'
```

Even better, pass the username as a parameter.

Per OP request, code snippet based on the comments:

```
    Query q = hibernateSession.createQuery("from Etudinat where Nom = :username");
q.setParameter("username", xxxx);       
Etudinat e = q.uniqueResult();
```

Comment: @David: absolutely not. This why I suggest passing username as a parameter. You can tell session to create a Query using HQL with parameter (where Nom = :username) and set parameter username to the value passed to your DAO. Then you can call uniqueResult() method on your query.

Comment: thank you , plz give me a ligne how to use the uniqueResult() i'v to that for tomorow